# WSO2 API Manager not able to get response from localhost

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2

I have a node based sample rest based application in Nodejs which is accessible by the url http://localhost:8288/api/users.
I have configured APIM and I was able to hit some sample services like https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=isbn:0747532699 and get the response back.

But when I try to hit my localhost rest service via API Manager using API Console, I am getting 
Response Body no content
Response Code 0
Response Headers{
  "error": "no response from server"
}

I have no error in the logs.But Neither call is reaching the backend rest service. Should i make some changes to access my localhost urls in API Manager.This API Manager installation and rest service is in the same machine.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if the browser does not trust the certificate of the APIM endpoint. Ideally what should happen is that you should install APIM certificate in your browser.

As a workaround, you can tell the browser to accept the certificate. For that, copy API URL to a new browser tab and accept the certificate.

Then try again in API console. It should work.

Comment: I just found out in my browser console , the below error is there

Mixed Content: The page at 'https://192.168.0.101:9443/store/apis/info?name=user&version=v1&provider=admin#!/default/get_getAll' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://192.168.0.101:9443/users/v1/getAll'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Can this be the reason?Is it the same fix which you have mentioned?

Comment: Is your URL an http one?

Comment: You can't send http requests from a https page. That's what it means by mixed content. As a workaround, you can change store url to `http://localhost:9763/store`.